# Plotting the 3D Heat Equation in 2D Slices

Tags: partial-differential-equations, 3d, matlab, heat-equation

I am trying to plot the temperature distribution of a cake using the heat equation in 3D in MATLAB. The boundary conditions are
[image: boundary conditions].

I am trying to plot the temperature distribution of a cake shaped as a rectangular prism on 2D slices. These slices are placed on the x-axis consecutively. (see below)
[image]

How can I visualize these slices? Is it also possible to make an animation of the temperature change over time for one of the slices? Thanks.

Comment: What is your formulation for the heat equation?

Comment: Are you asking about $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k\nabla^2 u$

Comment: Yes. It completes the question formulation.

Comment: There is not much to say about that if you want additional information. A simple homogeneous heat equation in 3D.